# In Java 8, can I use streams to filter a partial string?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In Java 8, can I use streams to filter a partial string?

Let us assume I have a list of animals like:

```
Brown Bear
Black Bear
Black Crow
Red Herring 
Owl
Sparrow
Blackbacked Flocking Crow
```

Let us assume all of the Animals names are in a list of Animals Objects

```
public class Animal{
    public name;
    public animalType;
}
```

Is there some way to find all of the animals that have Black regardless of the case somewhere in the name.  Something like the following...

```
List<Animal> filtList = employeeList.stream()
    .filter(x -> "%Black%".toUpperCase().equals(x.getLastName().toUpper()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no `toUpper()` method for `String`.

It is `toUpperCase()` and also you need to use `contains()` to check "BLACK" there anywhere in the whole string, so the code should be simple as shown below:

```
List<Employee> filtList = inputList.stream().
         filter(value -> value.toUpperCase().//convert to uppercase for checking
         contains("BLACK")).//filter values containing black
         collect(Collectors.toList());//collect as list
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use Stream.map for uppercase convertion

Answer (score 5):

Use regex:

```
List<Animal> filtList = list.stream()
   .filter(x -> x.getName().matches("(?i).*black.*"))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The regex flag `"(?)"` means "ignore case".